# Prevent code from running at import time

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cherrypy, python-multiprocessing

How do I get some code to run when a module is imported when the CherryPy web app starts and not when a new `Process` is created?

My CherryPy app follows this pattern:

**Main.py**

```
from Api1.Api1 import Api1
from Api2.Api2 import Api2
config = {'global': {'server.socket_host':  '0.0.0.0'}}
class Root():
    global config
    def __init__(self):
        self.app1 = App1('app1')
        self.app2 = App2('app2')
        config.update(self.app1.config)
        config.update(self.app2.config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/', config)
```

Here the `if __name__ == '__main__':` does it's job: `__name__ == '__main__'` when the server starts, and `__name__ == '__mp_main__'` when a new `Process` is created, so the `cherrypy.quickstart()` only happens once.

**App1\App1.py**

```
def every_hour():
    [...]
Monitor(cherrypy.engine, every_hour, frequency=60 * 60).start()
db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('app1.db', threadlocals=True)
class App1():
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        my_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.config = {'/%s/css' % root_dir: {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': '%s\\css' % my_path},
                       '/%s/img' % root_dir: {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': '%s\\img' % my_path}}
```

Here the same trick would not work because it's always `__name__ == 'App1.App1'`, so a new `Monitor` is started and a new database connection is created both at server startup and at `Process(target=some_func).start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to move the initialization code you have at the top-level of App1.py to a function, and then call that function from inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard in `main.py`:

**Main.py**

```
from App1.App1 import App1, app1_init
from App2.App2 import App2
config = {'global': {'server.socket_host':  '0.0.0.0'}}
class Root():
    global config
    def __init__(self):
        self.app1 = App1('app1')
        self.app2 = App2('app2')
        config.update(self.app1.config)
        config.update(self.app2.config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1_init()
    cherrypy.quickstart(Root(), '/', config)
```

**App1.py**

```
def every_hour():
    [...]

db = None
def app1_init():
    global db
    Monitor(cherrypy.engine, every_hour, frequency=60 * 60).start()
    db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('app1.db', threadlocals=True)

class App1():
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        my_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.config = {'/%s/css' % root_dir: {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': '%s\\css' % my_path},
                       '/%s/img' % root_dir: {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': '%s\\img' % my_path}}
```

It's not quite ideal, since anything importing `App1` will need to know to call `app1_init`, but it does work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code that is not within a method or class will be run on import, so if you have a file x.py that says only:

```
print("I'm just a poor boy, I need no sympathy")
```

and you have another file like yours importing this file, you will see a print of this text even before the main or init is started.

[Edit]Reading back my answer is a bit general maybe, but because of this your code outside of a class or function:

```
Monitor(cherrypy.engine, every_hour, frequency=60 * 60).start()
db = peewee.SqliteDatabase('app1.db', threadlocals=True)
```

Will be run on import as well.

Comment: I know... hence my question